# How to add data points as tooltip labels in Rechart even if they aren't plotted

Tags: charts, linechart, recharts

I have a simple line chart using Recharts where I plot the `dBm` for a cellular device. This is currently fine but we also have additional data that I want to display when you hover over the points in the graph, however those aren't really plotted because they aren't meant to be plotted. In this example, I want to show the service provider as well on the hover tooltip.

[image]

The way the graph is currently being generated is like this:

```html
<ResponsiveContainer id='graph-cellular-profile' width='100%' height={400}>
  <LineChart data={cellularDataLogs?.item} className='mt-10'>
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray='3 3' />
    <XAxis dataKey='timestamp' />
    <YAxis />
    <Tooltip />
    <Legend />
    <Brush dataKey='timestamp' height={30} stroke='#82ca9d' />
    <Line
      type='monotone'
      dataKey='datalogItem.signal_dBm'
      name='dBm'
      stroke='#82ca9d'
      strokeWidth={2}
      activeDot={{ r: 6 }}
    />
  </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

As you notice - in here I am plotting just the `signal_dBm` property. But I also have other properties like `provider`, `band`, and `channel` that I want to show when hovering over the data points.

All of the examples I've seen are only displaying labels on tooltips for data that are actually plotted on the graph.

Comment: Nevermind, found the documentation for what I'm trying to do: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomContentOfTooltip